# Pointers and assignmens in C language

Tags: c, pointers

Currently I am working on CFD code written in C language. As a beginner I am facing problems in understanding the pointers in C.

What does this command mean?

```
a = &obj->b
```

Comment: order of operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "get the address of the member b of the structure pointed by obj", it could be written this way :

```
a = & ( (*obj).b )
```

or using the structure dereference operator :

```
a = & ( obj->b )
```

But since the `->` operator has a higher priority than the `&` operator, the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: I would also add that the type of a is b's type*

Comment: Higher. `->` has higher precedence than `&`, otherwise one would need parentheses.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry my english may be wrong here but i thought that lowest precedence means highest priority, and if you look at this : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence you'll the precedence is 2 for `->` and 3 for `&`

Comment: Argh, I forgot that some people use that insane convention. In other places, the reasonable convention "higher precedence means the operator binds stronger" is followed. It's a mess. Good move using "priority", that's unambiguous.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to priority, I think it's less ambiguous now.

Answer (score 1):

`a = &obj->b`

This means that **a** holds the address (*&*) of the element **b** pointed to (*->*) by struct **obj**